# How to generate URL containing JSON as parameter for the GET action

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, parse-platform, httpurlconnection

I have the following curl command that works well to retrieve a list of json objects from my Parse.com project.

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {MY_APP_ID}" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {MY_REST_API}" -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: {MY_SESSION_TOKEN}" -G --data-urlencode "where={\"$relatedTo\":{\"object\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"_Role\",\"objectId\":\"{MY_OBJECT_ID}\"},\"key\":\"users\"}}" https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

Now I want to create a Java Servlet to do the same thing with HttpURLConnection. I created the following URL:

```
String url = "https://api.parse.com/1/users?where={\"$relatedTo\":{\"object\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"_Role\",\"objectId\":\"{MY_OBJECT_ID}\"},\"key\":\"users\"}}"

URL object = new URL(strUrl);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) object
                .openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", APP_ID);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST_API_KEY);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Session-Token", sessionToken);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Then I ended up with getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 36: https://api.parse.com/1/users?where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_Role","objectId":"{MY_OBJECT_ID}"},"key":"users"}}
```

I am kind of sure that it's the URL that threw out the error. But no idea how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: what is `str` and how it is related to `strUrl`? also you need `;` after string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to URL-encode the JSON content:

This is a util-method you could use (the exception will never throw).

```
static String urlEncode(String value) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return value;
    }
}

// ... in your code:

String url = "https://api.parse.com/1/users?where="

url += urlEncode(
    "{\"$relatedTo\":{\"object\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"_Role\",\"objectId\":\"{MY_OBJECT_ID}\"},\"key\":\"users\"}}"
);
```

I suppose that you replace `{MY_OBJECT_ID}` with the real ID and that you don't introduce the next bug in not encoding the ID in a JSON way. In that you could make your life easier when you use a JSON library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/).